# Week of year translation between c# and SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, date

So I'm at the end of a long programming binge and I have one logical hurdle left to get over. My application presents KPIs for quote requests. The business leads have asked for these KPIs to be broken down by week, and I imagine when that is complete the request will come for a breakdown by month. I've figured this out in my SQL queries:
`SELECT qpid FROM cpkpis WHERE DATEPART(ww, qpvalidfrom)=13 GROUP BY qpid;`
Which will give my a list of qpids to compute a total from and provide actual primary keys for drill down.
What I can't get my head around is how to get an enumeration of weeks of the year form my `C#` code. I've looked the `GregorianCalandar Class` and specifically the `GetWeekOfYear Method` but I'm having trouble coming up with an enumeration of those values.

My question then is this: given a date range [lets say `2013-01-14` through `2013-04-10`] how would I get an enumeration of the weeks of the year as `ints` between the start date and end date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From C#, an iterator is probably the simplest option:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> WeekNumbersBetween(
   DateTime startDate, 
   DateTime endDate, 
   Calendar calendar = null,
   CalendarWeekRule weekRule = CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
   DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
   if (calendar == null)
   {
      calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
   }

   DateTime week = startDate;
   while (week <= endDate)
   {
      yield return calendar.GetWeekOfYear(week, weekRule, firstDayOfWeek);
      week = week.AddDays(7);
   }
}
```

The default values for the `weekRule` and `firstDayOfWeek` parameters should match the default settings in SQL. If your settings are different, you'll need to specify the correct values.

Comment: Well done, much better than the for loop I was stuck on due to lack of sleep `int startWeek = GregorianCalandar.GetWeekOfYear(startDate`
                                  `, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek`
                                  `, DayOfWeek.Monday);`
`int endWeek =  GregorianCalandar.GetWeekOfYear(startDate`
                                  `, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek`
                                  `, DayOfWeek.Monday);`
`for(int i = startWeek; i<=endWeek;i++)`
`{`
`//Crappy business logic and sql injection prone database calls here`
`}`

Answer (score 3):

To help with with this task and the other requirements you're anticipating, you need a [date table](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/). IMHO the hardest thing to do in a database is to query data that isn't there.

You can query the date table:

```
Select Distinct DatePart(ww, dateField) as WeekNo
from DateTable
where dateField between '2013-01-14' and '2013-04-10';
```

Comment: Agreed but I would make a table with the grain down to day so that then you can derive both week and month from the day

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I very much appreciate the link to the date table article.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you could use something like:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2013-01-14';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2013-04-10';

WITH weekcte AS
     (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @StartDate), 0)) AS DateValue
       UNION ALL     
      SELECT DATEADD(wk, 1, DateValue)
        FROM weekcte
       WHERE DATEADD(wk, 1, DateValue) <= @EndDate )
SELECT DATEPART(ww, w.DateValue) AS 'Week No'
  FROM weekcte AS w;
```